# Best way to read data from ms excel without using JDBC ODBC driver

Tags: java

I don't want to use jdbc odbc to read data from excel because it is platform dependent .So After searching i find out about POI and jxl.jar from http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaExcel/article.html. Please suggest if there is any best way available which i can use.Can we use Excel_JDBC41.jar weather it is trusted jar or not

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) that is designed to work with Microsoft Documents.

Check related links that may helps you:

- http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/
- http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/
- [http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-read-excel-files-in-java-using-apache-poi/](http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-read-excel-files-in-java-using-apache-poi)

Comment: Can we use Excel_JDBC41.jar weather it is trusted jar or not

Answer (score 1):

The [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) is the best way!

Comment: Can we use Excel_JDBC41.jar weather it is trusted jar or not

Comment: I never used the Excel JDBC driver. I think that with this driver you will  be able access to the data only. But with Apache POI you can access to the design of tables - formatting, styles, etc.

Comment: Can I use Buffered Reader to make my own way to read excel because I don't need formatting , styles. If I don't need Apache POI.